# wordpress api unique keys/salts not properly inserted with lineinfile and uri module in ansible

Tags: wordpress, ansible

This is what I'm using to insert the text in wp-config:

```
- name: insert unique key and salts in wp-config
  lineinfile:
    path: /var/www/wordpress/wp-config.php
    regex: "put your unique phrase here"
    insertafter: "put your unique phrase here"
    line: "{{ api_info }}"
```

The api_info variables comes from main.yml under "handles":

```
 - name: get API information for wp-config
   uri:
    url: "https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/"
    return_content: yes
   register: api_info
```

The problem with this setup is that, instead of getting the nicely formatted keys wordpress provides, I get the text below. As you can see, there's also meta information, besides the content itself. Also \n is not translated into a new line but inserted as such:

{'status': 200, 'cookies': {}, 'date': 'Thu, 25 Oct 2018 19:57:00 GMT', 'url': 'https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/', 'transfer_encoding': 'chunked', 'changed': False, 'server': 'nginx', 'content': "define('AUTH_KEY',         '7Y1}w1mmjo ))zyP(E,0T@eWLkD.bU1: %WrS@#Rj,%L+Pd@JB[8^/]aZHj!Wpz-');\ndefine('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '1e`>3Msn1,~E/^.R}hx7R%GE}j/8q_;^qL|XcF|y#e2<Kr;:n%+BwW`Q$,U*0%Na');\ndefine('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    '*8UJMH*PX@VKfUF~l]+_O0(/HTz3wCGT=-#$++].bX Ry;A1+yw=>Acokm?)$+gneve+c db,/TQkR!262-9>-m');\ndefine('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '#n-i=.{7} [z3/-ay*qb+boD2D^nVjTqjUsKr,@3ACUxL).Un2K!Pf2|&');\ndefine('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   '+-!T;,|l,HNly(tA^bnPe7es1sKQg@');\n", 'failed': False, 'connection': 'close', 'content_type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8', 'msg': 'OK (unknown bytes)', 'redirected': False, 'x_frame_options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'cookies_string': ''}

Answer (score 0):

The content you desire is plainly there, in `api_info.content`, so that is what you should insert.

```
    line: "{{ api_info.content }}"
```

Comment: Great. It works just as expected.
In the meantime I also had a look at 'blockinfile', which in contrast to lineinfile, it doesn't create different line terminations (seen by vim) - which is quite annoying. But both work as expected
One more question, how could I have known I could use the ".content" suffix? Where can I get the documentation for that? Really helpful!

Comment: @Lethargos The [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/uri_module.html) explicitly says it: "Whether or not to return the body of the response as a 'content' key in the dictionary result. If the reported Content-type is 'application/json', then the JSON is additionally loaded into a key called `json` in the dictionary results." Failing that, you could use [`debug`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/debug_module.html) to print the value of `api_info`, which would then show you the response body in `content`. In fact, it's plainly visible in the text above!

Comment: Yes, but what I didn't find so obvious was the syntax itself, i.e. using .content ("dot content"). Where do I get a list of possible information that I can obtain?

Comment: In that very same documentation.